# How to set up Spring Boot and log4j2 properly?

Tags: java, logging, spring-boot, log4j2

How can I make Spring log properly via `log4j2` along with the other dependencies I have (Hibernate, Netty, Mina, etc.)?

I tried many different thins and dependency combinations. But I either can get Spring to log and nothing else, or everything but Spring.

With all dependecies logging properly (but Spring) I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory.getConfiguration(Lorg/apache/logging/log4j/core/config/ConfigurationSource;)Lorg/apache/logging/log4j/core/config/Configuration;
        at org.springframework.boot.logging.log4j2.Log4J2LoggingSystem.loadConfiguration(Log4J2LoggingSystem.java:167)
        at org.springframework.boot.logging.log4j2.Log4J2LoggingSystem.loadDefaults(Log4J2LoggingSystem.java:150)
        at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initializeWithConventions(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:75)
        at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initialize(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:50)
        at org.springframework.boot.logging.log4j2.Log4J2LoggingSystem.initialize(Log4J2LoggingSystem.java:140)
        at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initializeSystem(LoggingApplicationListener.java:277)
        at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initialize(LoggingApplicationListener.java:255)
        at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:224)
        at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:200)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:166)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:138)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:121)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.publishEvent(EventPublishingRunListener.java:111)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:65)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:54)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:329)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:306)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1185)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1174)
        at com.myproject.MyProject.main(MyProject.java:XX)
```

### This is my `build.gradle` dependencies

```
dependencies {
    // FIX engine
    compile 'org.quickfixj:quickfixj-all:1.6.2'
    compile 'org.apache.mina:mina-core:2.0.16'

    // Web API
    compile ('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.4.1.RELEASE') {
        // Remove default Spring loggers (where logback takes precedence)
        exclude module: 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
    }

    // Logging
    compile 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.7'
    compile 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.7'
    compile 'commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2' // for Spring logging
    compile 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-web:2.7' // for Spring logging
    compile 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl:2.7' // for Hibernate logging

    // ORM and Database Driver
    compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.2.4.Final'
    compile 'org.postgresql:postgresql:9.4.1209'

    // Key-value store
    compile 'biz.paluch.redis:lettuce:4.1.2.Final'

    // Testing
    // The Groovy language
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.6'
    // Spock testing framework
    testCompile 'org.spockframework:spock-core:1.0-groovy-2.4'
}
```

Then, getting rid of my logging dependencies and adding the dependecy below:

```
 compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2:1.4.1.RELEASE'
```

Spring logging will work, but the other deps logging will not.

### This is the `main` method (nothing special)

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Fine tune a few logging settings so they don't log with TRACE or DEBUG levels.
        Configurator.setLevel("org.hibernate", Level.ERROR);
        Configurator.setLevel("org.jboss", Level.ERROR);
        Configurator.setLevel("org.apache.mina", Level.ERROR);
        Configurator.setLevel("io.netty", Level.ERROR);
        Configurator.setLevel("quickfix.mina", Level.WARN);
        Configurator.setLevel("com.lambdaworks", Level.WARN);

        // ...

        logger.info("FIX Controller started. Loading the API.");

        SpringApplication.run(MyProject.class, args);
    }
```

So again, how can I get Spring to log properly via `log4j2` along with the other dependencies I have?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Spring Boot 1.4.1 is built with and supports Log4J 2.6 but you're trying to use 2.7. Unfortunately that doesn't work as there's a breaking API change in 2.7 that  was made in [this commit](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/commit/85c5e81a4bca677bf02dc9be4f2dff3d1f0450c1#diff-ac196c5434fe9d75842ccc854b05145d). This is the cause of the `NoSuchMethodError` that you're seeing.

Dropping back to Log4J2 2.6.2 should fix the problem. Alternatively, you could upgrade to Spring Boot 1.5 which uses Log4J 2.7.

Comment: Reverting back to 2.6 on all 2.7 `log4j2` dependencies fixed it! Thank you. I think that the `org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory.getConfiguration` method is `static` in 2.6, but not in 2.7, thus breaking the API.

Comment: Spring Boot 1.5.1 is released! https://spring.io/blog/2017/01/30/spring-boot-1-5-1-released

Comment: @K.C. Yes! by putting 2.7 for the log4j dependencies, I have no errors :)

Comment: This is the right answer! This worked in my case - even though I was using the 1.2 bridge, it didn't work without updating Spring boot to the latest 1.5.